# Using Hibernate XML Mappings in Play2 Framework

Tags: hibernate, scala, jpa, playframework-2.0

I'm researching into how to use Hibernate XML mapping files in Play, since I don't really see where I would put them (package structure is very different). I've read about using JPA but all the examples I see use annotations for the mappings.

In my case I want to map to classes that are in a dependency I have, so the Annotations will not work.

Can anyone point to how I could do this in Play2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* JPA is getting resources from the classpath. Try putting your mapping in the conf folder.